# Como é implementada a função find?

Tags: regex, pseudocódigo, autômatos

Diferentemente do `match()` que procura por uma ocorrência de uma **linguagem** *y* no **início** da string, o `find()` faz uma **busca** por *y* dentro dessa string. Eu **poderia** utilizar o algoritmo de [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) para procurar por a ***primeira ocorrência*** `n0, n1, ..., n` de *X*(string) em *S*(string) em complexidade `O(n+k)`, sendo `n` o tamanho de *X* e `k` o tamanho de *S*, mas isso é inviável na implementação do autômato de busca por causa das transições de estado **(creio eu, pois o algoritmo apenas olha ao início da string, eu preciso implementá-lo para que uma determinada linguagem,  possa ser encontrada tanto no início/meio/fim)**.

Alguém pode me trazer uma luz sobre isso?

Comment: Não estou entendendo a sua pergunta direito. Um autômato finito determinístico vai processar a string de entrada em tempo O(n) e o algoritmo KMP é eficiente justamente pq ele constrói um autômato finito ao invés de fazer uma busca ingênua...

Comment: Sim, isso é óbvio, o problema é MANUSEAR OS ESTADOS da DFA/NFA da linguagem que eu estou buscando dentro de S. O meu problema é esse, não faço a menor ideia de como implementar isso.

Comment: Talvez, eu possa chamar KMP(char) em cada estado da minha DFA e assim ir montando os retornos aceitáveis. Isso seria caro pois eu teria O(n+1) a cada char, a não ser que, eu altere o KMP para manter a posição atual no buffer.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Boyer–Moore, not Knuth-Morris-Pratt? http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html

Comment: Você quer encontrar uma string fixa dentro de outra string, ou achar uma regex dentro da string? E perguntar "como é implementada" sem especificar uma linguagem/plataforma é complicado de responder, pois cada uma pode fazer isso de uma forma diferente (existem [diversos métodos de busca em string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm), bem como [diversos métodos de casamento de padrão](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Implementations_and_running_times), e nem sempre o "mais eficiente" - se é que existe - é usado na prática, por razões que variam caso a caso).

Comment: @mgibsonbr, eu coloquei a tag pseudocódigo por isso.

Comment: Porque não construir o clássico DFA/NFA para `.*expressao-regular` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Construa um parser LR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) a partir das produções:

```
s -> .*minha_regex
minha_regex -> sua regex original
```

Quando a produção `minha_regex` for reduzida pela primeira vez, você terá achado.

Converter partes da regex em produções é relativamente símple:

- `a -> x*` é o mesmo que:

  ```
  a -> ε
  a -> a x
  ```
- `a -> x | y` é o mesmo que:

  ```
  a -> x
  a -> y
  ```
- `a -> (x | y) z*` é o mesmo que:

  ```
  a -> a0 a1
  a0 -> x
  a0 -> y
  a1 -> ε
  a1 -> a1 z
  ```

Comment: Grande ideia, Miguel.

Answer (score 0):

***Regex - EM JAVA*** (você não disse a linguagem, espero que ajude!)

As expressões regulares(regex), é um recurso onde podemos estar fazendo busca com apenas simples caracteres (sequência de letras, dígitos, etc) ou com metacaracteres. Logo, para utilizarmos tais vantagens precisamos obviamente, indicar uma fonte e os caracteres de buscas.

De Matcher os métodos: find(), start(), group(), end();

Temos como fonte: **mouse da cor azul**. Logo, quero encontrar onde estar a palavra cor, na nossa frase(em negrito). E agora!?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher; 
import java.util.regex.Pattern; 

public class Regex { 

public static void main(String[] args) { 

String fonte = “mouse da cor azul”; 

String queremosIsso = “cor”; 

/*
* Nesse momento obteremos uma instância de Pattern, através do * método 
* static compile(String regex), o qual recebe uma String que é a 
* expressção regular 
*/ 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(queremosIsso); 

/* 
* Aqui, atravÃ©s da instancia de Pattern, chamando o método * matcher() e passando a fonte de busca 
*/ 

Matcher m = p.matcher(fonte); 

//Ligando o motor 
while (m.find()) { 

//Obtendo o inicio do que foi encontrado 
System.out.println(m.start()); 

} 

} 

}
```

Ao executarmos este código, obteremos como resposta 9(nove). Mas, por que 9?

Primeiro vamos ver o que acontece.

Após termos obtidos as instancias de Pattern e Matcher, em um loop(while) chamamos o método m.find(). Ao chamarmos este cara, o motor regex é disparado, ou seja, a tarefa de busca é efetivamente iniciada. Vale lembra que o motor regex, executa a busca da esquerda para a direita e ao passo que ele encontrar uma ocorrência, está não participara mais do processo de busca. Logo abaixo no código, chamei o método m.start(). Esse método retorna um inteiro, onde este representa, o índice inicial de cada sequencia encontrada, que neste caso seria 9(nove). Lembrabdo que começa do zero. Abaixo segue as letras e seus índices(onde estiver duas aspas sem conteúdo, representam espaços).

0-m 1-o 2-u 3-s 4-e 5-’ ‘ 6-d 7-a 8-’ ‘ 9-c

mouse da cor azul

Existe também como falei no início, o método group(). Este é responsável por trazer o grupo de caracteres que foi encontrado na busca.

Ex: //Ligando o motor

```
while (m.find()) { 

//Obtendo o inicio do que foi encontrado 

System.out.println(m.start() +” “+ m.group() +” “+ m.end()); 

}
```

Terá como saída: 9 cor 12

Em seguida o método end(), onde este é a contra partida de start( ), trazendo o índice do ultimo caracter encontrado, porém esse o índice inicia no um(1).

Fonte:http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-a-regex/15597